# Nexus does not start with my new SSL keystore.jks

Tags: ssl, nexus, keystore, keytool

I have created a new SSL certificate for my Nexus 2 server.
When I start it, the app fails with the message

```
java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key
```

Here are the logs of the wrapper when I try starting it.

```
jvm 1    | 2023-06-13 18:25:02,127+0200 ERROR [WrapperListener_start_runner] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.jsw.JswLauncher - Failed to start
jvm 1    | java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key
jvm 1    |      at sun.security.provider.KeyProtector.recover(KeyProtector.java:328) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
jvm 1    |      at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineGetKey(JavaKeyStore.java:146) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
jvm 1    |      at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineGetKey(JavaKeyStore.java:56) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
jvm 1    |      at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineGetKey(KeyStoreDelegator.java:96) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
jvm 1    |      at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineGetKey(JavaKeyStore.java:70) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
jvm 1    |      at java.security.KeyStore.getKey(KeyStore.java:1023) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
jvm 1    |      at sun.security.ssl.SunX509KeyManagerImpl.<init>(SunX509KeyManagerImpl.java:133) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
jvm 1    |      at sun.security.ssl.KeyManagerFactoryImpl$SunX509.engineInit(KeyManagerFactoryImpl.java:70) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
jvm 1    |      at javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory.init(KeyManagerFactory.java:256) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.getKeyManagers(SslContextFactory.java:1080) ~[jetty-util-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.doStart(SslContextFactory.java:291) ~[jetty-util-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64) ~[jetty-util-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSelectChannelConnector.doStart(SslSelectChannelConnector.java:612) ~[jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
jvm 1    |      at org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.jetty.InstrumentedSslSelectChannelConnector.doStart(InstrumentedSslSelectChannelConnector.java:91) ~[nexus-bootstrap-2.14.4-03.jar:2.14.4-03]
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64) ~[jetty-util-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:293) ~[jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64) ~[jetty-util-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
jvm 1    |      at org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.jetty.JettyServer$JettyMainThread.run(JettyServer.java:247) ~[nexus-bootstrap-2.14.4-03.jar:2.14.4-03]
```

With the old keystore.jks, the server starts without any pb.
When I check the password used to access the keystore.jks, I have no problem.

Both commands work with the same password.

```
keytool -list -v -keystore keystore.jks.old
keytool -list -v -keystore keystore.jks.new
```

The CN used in both keystore is the same. There must be something wrong with the new keystore.jks. however, I do not know what. Any idea to debug the problem ?

Comment: There might be something referring to the old key or something like this in my nexus config. However, as far as I can see, only the jetty-https.xml refers to the keystore.jks file.

Comment: Did you (or someone) create the new.jks with a _key_ password different from the store password? `keytool -list -v` doesn't check this because it doesn't (try to) unwrap privatekey item(s). Try `keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore new.jks -destkeystore junk.jks` and see whether it prompts for a key password separate/different from the source store password. PS: 8u101 is 7 years old.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085  Thanks for the tip. Indeed the pkcs12 was created with another password. I did notice that when I created the keystore. However, I did not realize that this could have had an impact. By realigning the passwords, it is now working fine. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As explained by dave, the problem came from the fact that the pkcs12 was encrypted with another password. My keytool -list command did not check that password, that is why I could not distinguish the difference between the old and the new keystore.jks